# InvokeAsync is intermittent

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Sometimes my signalr .net client's InvokeAsync method works and sometimes it doesn't.

I have a .net core 2.2 project which has an Azure signalR service hub, in my startup.cs i have set it up like this:

```
services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = 
true).AddAzureSignalR(connstring);

app.UseAzureSignalR(route =>
{
    route.MapHub<FooBarHub>("/foobarhub");
});
```

I have a .net client project which is a winform app (.net 4.6.1), it sets up the connection like :

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($" 
{serviceHost}/AgentHub").Build();
```

when it starts up I call:

```
await connection.StartAsync();
```

and can see the state is Connected.

I then want to call a method on the hub from the client so i do this in the client:

```
string myIdString = await connection.InvokeAsync<string> 
("RegisterSignalRId", foobarId);
```

that should hit my method in my server hub:

```
public string RegisterSignalRId(string foobarId)
{
    myService.RegisterSignalRId(this.Context.ConnectionId, foobarId);
    return this.Context.ConnectionId;
}
```

My problem is that sometimes when I start the winform app, I get myIdString being set to null, it doesn't hit the breakpoint in the server hub method at all, and yet sometimes it does work and I get the real/correct value.

I can't consistently make it work or fail, it seems random.

Comment: After some more digging i think this is because i'm using an Azure signalR service.  I've added a new method which is sometimes hits and sometimes says . HubException: Method does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was that i'd checked in (to source control) my azure service's connection string, so other devs were also using this and pointing their versions of the API service at that azure service.  So when i ran my code sometimes azure would hit my API service with the new method in and it would work, sometimes it would hit someone else's api and so fail because their code didn't have the new method in.